# Reference input ngModel to object in ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to generate dynamic form using the array. In that array I am providing the FieldLabel & DataModel.
Here I want to use DataModel as the object reference. I want to update the referenced model when user update the value in Input Field.
I have searched a lot but not able to find the solution yet.

Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

I have tried Iterating the model and used the DataModel attribute in [(ngModel)] but it is taking that as a STRING (which is valid)  but I don't want this. I want to reference the main object instead of taking that as a string.

```
obj : any = {
      FirstName:"Taha",
      MiddleName:"Faheem",
      LastName:"Hussain",
      Address:
        {
          CurrentAddress:"USA",
          PermanentAddress:"Pakistan"
        }
  }

  fields: any[] = [
    {
      "FieldLabel": "First Name",
      "DataModel": "obj.FirstName"
    },
    {
      "FieldLabel": "Middle Name",
      "DataModel":"obj.MiddleName"
    },
    {
      "FieldLabel": "Current Address",
      "DataModel":"obj.Address.CurrentAddress"
    }  
  ];
```

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
    <input placeholder="{{field.FieldLabel | uppercase}}" [(ngModel)]="field.DataModel">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input placeholder="Last Name" [(ngModel)]="obj.LastName">
  </div>
  <br> {{obj|json}}
</div>
```

I want to update the obj with the value user enter in ngFor input fields.

I am working to generated the complete dynamic form along with the formula on each fields using this approach.
Is there any better approach to get the desired result?

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using reactive forms? They are far more flexible, and allow for properly dynamic forms.

Answer (score 1):

By creating fields array and having DataModel, you have disconnected the original "obj" with input. If you want to take this approach then do following [Or see the following stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdpqog?file=app/app.component.ts]-

```
obj : any = {
      FirstName:"Taha",
      MiddleName:"Faheem",
      LastName:"Hussain"
  }

  fields: any[] = [
    {
      "FieldLabel": "Person Name",
      "property": 'FirstName',
      "value": this.obj.FirstName
    },
    {
      "FieldLabel": "Current Address",
      "property": 'MiddleName',
      "value": this.obj.MiddleName
    } 
  ];

  onChange($event, field) {
    this.obj[field.property] = $event;
  }

<div class="container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
    <input placeholder="{{field.FieldLabel | uppercase}}" [ngModel]="field.value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, field)">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input placeholder="Last Name" [(ngModel)]="obj.LastName">
  </div>
  <br> {{obj|json}}
</div>
```